# Adding multiple columns at certain positions in dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tibble

I have a dataframe that looks similar to this one:

```
> df <- data.frame(A1=1:3, B1=1:3, A2=1:3, B2=1:3, A3=1:3, B3=1:3)
> df

  A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 B3
1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3  3  3  3
```

Now, I'm looking for some code that adds rows before B1, B2 and B3:

```
  A1 AB1 B1 A2 AB2 B2 A3 AB3 B3
1  1   X  1  1   X  1  1   X  1
2  2   X  2  2   X  2  2   X  2
3  3   X  3  3   X  3  3   X  3
```

As the dataframe above is only a minimum, reproducible example (the real dataframe is much larger), I'm looking for a solution either using a for loop or a solution with tidyverse. I had the idea to use a combination of a for loop and `add_column` from the tibble package:

```
library(tibble)
  
  for (i in 1:3) {
    df <- df %>%
      add_column(paste0("AB", i, "") = "X" , .before = paste0("B", i, ""))
  }
```

Unfortunately, the idea does not work. I'm not quite sure if the whole approach is wrong, or if there is anything wrong with the `paste0()` etc.. If you need any further information, please let me know. T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a slight tweak your code works although there's probably better ways to do this:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  df <- df %>%
    add_column(!!paste0("AB", i, collapse = "") := "X" , .before = paste0("B", i, collapse =  ""))
}
```